# Why a simple varchar insert with characters such as "?" and ":" asking for binding variables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, toad

I'm executing MySQL scripts (Inserts) from TOAD, if my simple varchar field contains "?" or ":", the TOAD asks me to bind variables (@f0) when all I want is to insert that "?" and ":" **LITERALLY** from the sentence.

I need to **SET sql_mode = 'PIPES_AS_CONCAT'** and replace all instance of **"?"** and **":"** to **|| CHAR(63) ||** to make it valid. If I escape with **"\?"** or **"\:"** it's no use, not like when escaping other special character which works.

```
INSERT INTO `specs` (`ID`, `ParentProductsID`, `SpecsGroup`, `SpecsSubGroup`, `SpecsSubGroup2`, `SpecsText`) VALUES (1289, 27, 'What\'s in the box?', '', '', 'User guide');
```

This statement asks to bind variable @f0, unless I make it like this which works fine but longer:

```
SET sql_mode = 'PIPES_AS_CONCAT';
INSERT INTO `specs` (`ID`, `ParentProductsID`, `SpecsGroup`, `SpecsSubGroup`, `SpecsSubGroup2`, `SpecsText`) VALUES (1289, 27, 'What\'s in the box' || CHAR(63) || '', '', '', 'User guide');
```

Is there an easier way?

**Note:** I'm using TOAD for MySQL, this might not be happening for other SQL Editor I suspect.

**Update:** This works fine when I tried in PHPMyAdmin, it treats the "?" literally in every inserts.

Comment: Is there an easier way? Yes, use `PDO` or `MySQLi` **Prepared Statements**. If you're using MySQL directly look in settings to turn off Prepared Statements preperation (*I guess....*)

Comment: If you get the SQL from json you have a programming Language to access  the database, so you can do all logic there. Including using prepared statements

Comment: Also it is very risky to send SQL Statements overn an API and execute it.

Comment: I'm not using PHP here and disregard the JSON part because that's only a background story, I'm only doing what is required of me by creating a tool to generate MySQL INSERT Script from JSON with JavaScript. 
||
My real question is why the editor (in this case TOAD) is asking me to bind variables when my varchar field contains "?" or ":" and I can't escape it with backslash in MySQL Scripting.

Answer (score 0):

> This is not (*yet*) an answer but more detailed questions:

I suspect what is happening is that somehow the strings are being escaped so the SQL doesn't realise the `?`/`:` are literal.

Have you [read the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)?

- Does TOAD auto-escape the SQL commands given to it (thus double escaping)?
- Can you work directly with the MySQL command line and see if the problem stil appears?
- Can you try inserting data `here?` with a string which does not contain ay quote, escaped or otherwise to see if these factors are related?
- Can you try using some other SQL interface if you can't use the command line, to see if the issue is specific to TOAD?
- Can you check TOAD settings to ensure that it hasn't been set to automatically somehow expect every SQL to be a Prepared Statement. (*yeah clutching at straws... but always check the settings!*)